# extend derivations of ore domain to its quotient field

Tags: associative-algebras, noncommutative-rings

I wonder whether someone knows a good reference(textbook or paper) for the following result:

Any derivation of ore domain may be extended unqiuely to a derivation of its quotient field.

Thanks.